# Multivariable Chain Rule Stewart Early Transcendentals 47

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Does anyone know how could I approach this?
if $z = \frac{1}{x} [f(x - y) + g(x + y)]$, show that
$$
\frac{∂}{∂x}(x^2 \frac{∂z}{∂x}
)=x^2 \frac{∂^2 z}{∂y^2}$$

I've tried by substituting $u=x-y$ and $v=x+y$

Comment: Start with what $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ are. Just work your way through them one step at a time. It is entirely fine to substitute $u(x,y)=x-y$ and $v(x,y)=x+y$ if that makes you more comfortable with the chain rule. How far do you get before you're stuck?

Comment: I just compute the partial derivatives of z respect to x and y, then I don't know where exactly to go after that

Comment: Ok, cool. That's a big step of the way. What did you get? It might be a good idea to put the result in your question post so others who read your question can see it.

Comment: Ok, but first could you correct me if I made a mistake with my reasoning? I'm working with 3 functions right? $u(x,y)=x-y$, $v(x,y)=x+y$ and $x(x,y)=x$, so $\frac{∂z}{∂x}=\frac{∂z}{∂u} \frac{∂u}{∂x}+\frac{∂z}{∂v} \frac{∂v}{∂x}+\frac{∂z}{∂x} \frac{∂x}{∂x}$ Or that's wrong?

Comment: That looks good. But you have to remember that the $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ on the left means something different from the $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ on the right. The one on the left is the one you're after, while the one on the right you ignore that $u$ and $v$ are functions (which is much easier to calculate, but not the full answer you're after).

Comment: So what I got was: $\frac{∂z}{∂x}= \frac{∂z}{∂u} +  \frac{∂z}{∂v} +  \frac{∂z}{∂x}$ and $\frac{∂z}{∂y}= - \frac{∂z}{∂u} +  \frac{∂z}{∂v}$

Comment: Mhm. Now it's time for actual calculations.

Comment: Ok, but that's the part where I get all confused, could you tell me how to do it or some book or something to guide me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.

Rather, let $h(x,y)=f(x-y)+g(x+y)$ so you can work with its partial derivatives and the quotient rule.

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}&=\dfrac{\partial ~~}{\partial x}\dfrac{h(x,y)}{x}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{x~h_x(x,y)-h(x,y)}{x^2}\end{align}$$

And so forth.

---

Where $h_{x}(x,y) = f'(x-y)+g'(x+y)$, and $h_y(x,y)=-f'(x-y)+g'(x+y)$, by the chain rule, et cetera.